# how to install gd library with php 7 centos 6.5

Tags: php

i use laravel 5, when upload, i get error "GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation.". When i install GD Library i get error.

```
Resolving Dependencies
    --> Running transaction checkenter code here
    ---> Package php-gd.i686 0:5.5.32-1.el6.remi will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-32) = 5.5.32-1.el6.remi for package: php-gd-5.5.32-1.el6.remi.i686
    --> Processing Dependency: gd-last(x86-32) >= 2.1.1 for package: php-gd-5.5.32-1.el6.remi.i686
    --> Processing Dependency: libvpx.so.1 for package: php-gd-5.5.32-1.el6.remi.i686
    --> Processing Dependency: libt1.so.5 for package: php-gd-5.5.32-1.el6.remi.i686
    --> Processing Dependency: libgd.so.3 for package: php-gd-5.5.32-1.el6.remi.i686
    --> Processing Dependency: libXpm.so.4 for package: php-gd-5.5.32-1.el6.remi.i686
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package gd-last.i686 0:2.1.1-2.el6.remi will be installed
    ---> Package libXpm.i686 0:3.5.10-2.el6 will be installed
    ---> Package libvpx.i686 0:1.3.0-5.el6_5 will be installed
    ---> Package php-gd.i686 0:5.5.32-1.el6.remi will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-32) = 5.5.32-1.el6.remi for package: php-gd-5.5.32-1.el6.remi.i686
    ---> Package t1lib.i686 0:5.1.2-6.el6_2.1 will be installed
    --> Finished Dependency Resolution
    Error: Package: php-gd-5.5.32-1.el6.remi.i686 (remi-php55)
               Requires: php-common(x86-32) = 5.5.32-1.el6.remi
               Installed: php-common-7.0.0-0.12.RC8.el6.remi.i686 (@remi-php70)
                   php-common(x86-32) = 7.0.0-0.12.RC8.el6.remi
               Available: php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.i686 (base)
                   php-common(x86-32) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6
               Available: php-common-5.3.3-46.el6_6.i686 (updates)
                   php-common(x86-32) = 5.3.3-46.el6_6
               Available: php-common-5.3.3-46.el6_7.1.i686 (updates)
                   php-common(x86-32) = 5.3.3-46.el6_7.1
               Available: php-common-5.4.45-3.el6.remi.i686 (remi)
                   php-common(x86-32) = 5.4.45-3.el6.remi
               Available: php-common-5.4.45-4.el6.remi.i686 (remi)
                   php-common(x86-32) = 5.4.45-4.el6.remi
               Available: php-common-5.5.31-1.el6.remi.i686 (remi-php55)
                   php-common(x86-32) = 5.5.31-1.el6.remi
               Available: php-common-5.5.32-1.el6.remi.i686 (remi-php55)
                   php-common(x86-32) = 5.5.32-1.el6.remi
     You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
     You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to above output, you have remi-php55 enabled, but php 7.0 installed from remi-php70.

So you need to:

- disable remi-php55 repository
- enable  remi-php70 repository

Using

```
yum install yum-utils
yum-config-manager --enable  remi-php70
yum-config-manager --disable remi-php55
```

Comment: before i run command yum install yum-utils, then yum-config-manager --enable  remi-php70
yum-config-manager --disable remi-php55

Comment: Right, you need yum-utils. I just edit my answer and update the wizard to add this information, see http://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/